# Is equivalent labelling enough to prove isomorphism between two graphs?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Determine whether the following graphs are isomorphic.
[image]

Labelling vertices of both graphs as $u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4$ in the order given above, we see that these graphs are bipartite with $u_i\leftrightarrow v_j$ iff $i\ne j$. Is showing this correspondence enough to prove that they are isomorphic? Is that because the labellings allow us to write adjacency matrices, equivalency of which supports isomorphism between them?

Comment: To actually prove they're isomorphic you'd need to explicitly show that that the edges are in one-to-one corresponding by the mapping.  One way to do this would be to explicitly list all of the edges in $G_1$ in $G_2$ and demonstrate that they correspond.

Comment: @MorganRodgers It just depends on your standard of 'proof'. I suppose you could consider the picture as proof since you could verify it from there. One way or another you have to show that the mapping is an isomorphism.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A graph isomorphism $G_1\cong G_2$ is by definition a bijection $\varphi\colon V(G_1)\to V(G_2)$ between the sets of vertices of $G_1$ and $G_2$ such that $(u,v)$ is an edge in $G_1$ if and only if $(\varphi(u),\varphi(v))$ is an edge in $G_2$.

Your labeling of vertices achieves exactly that: you have constructed a bijection between the sets of vertices and verified that it send edges to edges and non-edges to non-edges.

Hence, you have shown $G_1\cong G_2$.